# Angular JS - PHP - Firefox 48 - Which is the best solution to do unit tests ?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, selenium, firefox

I create a Web application which use PHP, Angular JS 1.5 and which is only used on the lastest version of Firefox(v48).

I have too many options now to do unit tests manualy. Therefore, I was looking for a solution to automize them. I spent 3 days to install Selenium correctly when at the last step, I understood that Firefox 48 is not compatible with Selenium. I don't want to downgrade my Firefox just for that and create security matters or lost my plugins. I'm looking for an other solution to do it... Someone has a good idea ?

Comment: How is Selenium supposed to fit the equation? It isn't necessary for unit tests.

Comment: I want to run a set of UI tests.

Comment: Karma is generally used to run unit tests. It doesn't need Selenium.